# Linked hash map in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a project and I have the following issue: the project is something related to students. The class Student contains 3 fields id, name, grade. I have to represent the students collection using a linkedHashMap, id being the key.
I have tried this but I'm not sure is ok because the name  is a string and the grade an int.

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList>();
```

Could you give me some ideas how to represent this collection? I need to be able to add/remove a student.

Comment: You probably want to look at a tree map - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html where the key is the student object and the values are an integer of the grades.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just map from integer to student then?

```
Map<Integer,Student> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Student>();
```

Add students via

```
myMap.put(student.id(), student);
```

A linked hash map preserves insertion order. A TreeMap would keep the students sorted by id; a plain HashMap avoids some overhead compared to a LinkedHashMap when no particular order is required.

Answer (score 0):

You may include another `LinkedHashMap` inside first one.

Your declaration would be like:

```
Map<Integer, LinkedHashMap> my Map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap>();
```

Or you might use a TreeMap instead.

Then you can just use the `put`, `get` and `remove` methods. Remember you can also use `keySet` and `values` to iterate and even `containsKey`.

Comment: I can't use TreeMap because LinkedHashMap is required for this project :) I've read about it

Comment: i agree with the other answer, I even already implemented SAME thing in the same way with HashMaps, I may share the code if you want.

Comment: I could use an example to follow, if you want to share your code I'm opened

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom classes inside a `Map`:

**`Usuario` class**

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private String  nombre;
    private String  ciudadOrigen;
    private String  paisOrigen;
    private String  idiomaMaterno;
    private int     edad;

    public Usuario(String nombre, String ciudadOrigen, String paisOrigen, String idiomaMaterno, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ciudadOrigen = ciudadOrigen;
        this.paisOrigen = paisOrigen;
        this.idiomaMaterno = idiomaMaterno;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String paisOrigen, String idiomaMaterno) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.paisOrigen = paisOrigen;
        this.idiomaMaterno = idiomaMaterno;
    }

    public Usuario(String nombre, String ciudadOrigen, String paisOrigen, String idiomaMaterno) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.ciudadOrigen = ciudadOrigen;
        this.paisOrigen = paisOrigen;
        this.idiomaMaterno = idiomaMaterno;
    }

    public String getIdiomaMaterno() {
        return idiomaMaterno;
    }

    public void setIdiomaMaterno(String idiomaMaterno) {
        this.idiomaMaterno = idiomaMaterno;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getCiudadOrigen() {
        return ciudadOrigen;
    }

    public void setCiudadOrigen(String ciudadOrigen) {
        this.ciudadOrigen = ciudadOrigen;
    }

    public String getPaisOrigen() {
        return paisOrigen;
    }

    public void setPaisOrigen(String paisOrigen) {
        this.paisOrigen = paisOrigen;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
 }
```

**`Saludo` class**

```
public class Saludo implements Serializable {

    private String saludo;
    private String idioma;

    public Saludo(String saludo, String idioma) {
        this.saludo = saludo;
        this.idioma = idioma;
    }

    public String getIdioma() {
        return idioma;
    }

    public void setIdioma(String idioma) {
        this.idioma = idioma;
    }

    public String getSaludo() {
        return saludo;
    }

    public void setSaludo(String saludo) {
        this.saludo = saludo;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class ModeloDatos implements Serializable {

    private HashMap<Usuario, Saludo> usuariosSaludos = new HashMap<>();

    public void ingresar (Usuario usuario, Saludo saludo) {

        usuariosSaludos.put(usuario, saludo);
    }

    public String obtenerUsuarios () {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        if (usuariosSaludos.isEmpty()) return "Lista vacía";

        else {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Lista de usuarios:\n");

            for (Usuario usuario : usuariosSaludos.keySet()) 
                stringBuilder.append(usuario.getNombre()).
                              append(" de ").
                              append(usuario.getPaisOrigen()).
                              append(".\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String obtenerSaludos () {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        if (usuariosSaludos.isEmpty()) return "Lista vacía";

        else {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Lista de saludos:\n");

            for (Saludo saludo : usuariosSaludos.values()) 
                stringBuilder.append("Se dice ").
                              append(saludo.getSaludo()).
                              append(" en ").
                              append(saludo.getIdioma()).
                              append(".\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String obtenerResultados() {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        if (usuariosSaludos.isEmpty()) return "Lista vacía";

        else {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Resultados:\n\n");

            for (Usuario usuario : usuariosSaludos.keySet()) {

                Saludo s = usuariosSaludos.get(usuario);

                stringBuilder.append(usuario.getNombre()).
                              append(" de ").
                              append(usuario.getPaisOrigen()).
                              append(".\n").
                              append("Nos dice ").
                              append(s.getSaludo()).
                              append("en ").
                              append(s.getIdioma()).append("\n\n");
            }
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();        

    }
}
```

Where:

- `ingresar` adds an entry to the map using `put` method.
- `obtenerUsuarios` iterates over the map's keys using `keySet` method.
- `obtenerSaludos` iterates over the map's values using `values` method.
- `obtenerResultados` is a combination of both methods.

Comment: By the way, *Usuario* means "User" and *Saludo* means "Greeting". That's spanish ;)

Comment: I use `StringBuilder` to construct Strings while iterating over the Map.

Comment: Thanks I will explore it deeply but now I don't really have the time to do it. I promise that after I do it I'll come back with an answer

Comment: No worries, in your case you would only have an Integer as Key. So far would be exactly the same programm ;)

Comment: Thank you it helped me to fix my problem :)

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad it was useful. Remember you can always pick a correct answer ;)